# how to determine if a method has been overriden?

Tags: java

Consider the following scenario:

I am working on a framework that allows users to subclass a particular abstract class provided by the framework, which will allow them to insert their own functionality into the flow of the application.

For example a class like this:

```
public class MyAbstractClass {
    protected String step1(String input) {
        // default implementation
    }

    public final void process(MyObject objct) {
        // some steps
        String someData = step1(object.getInput());
        // some more steps
    }
}
```

Now, in a newer version of the framework, I want to change the step1 method to use some object (which can be converted to the argument of the current step1 method) as a parameter. However, I do not want to break the code for the users who have already extended this class.

I am currently planning to do it this way:

```
public class MyAbstractClass {

    private boolean isOldStep1Overriden = true;

    protected String step1(MyObject input) {
        String oldValue = step1(input.getInput());
        if (isOldStep1Overriden) {
            // the method has been overriden - some logic here to handle this (assume this logic is known)
        } else {
            // the method has not been overriden - ignore the old value and carry out the new default processing
        }
    }

    @Deprecated
    protected String step1(String input) {
        // default implementation
        isOldStep1Overriden = false;
    }

    public final void process(MyObject objct) {
        // some steps
        String someData = step1(object);
        // some more steps
    }
}
```

Are there any other ways to implement such a use case?

The following options are also on hold :

- Create a new abstract class for the new implementation - This would prevent existing users from getting the new features without modifying their code.
- Use reflection - I would prefer not to, if possible

EDIT: Some more relevant background information:

The framework in question is actually an application which is deployed to a shared location, and users (developers) of this framework submit extensions to be installed in it. So the application itself could be upgraded without the developers of the extensions having made any changes to their code. To take an example of a similar system, consider firefox and its addons - both developed by separate teams, and firefox can be updated without the addon developer's knowledge.

Comment: seeing as in a standard application, the abstract class has no knowledge of a(ny) subclasses, how would you do this? Just change it, if that is what needs to happen, you won't be breaking anything. After all, the users would have to update to the new version to get this change.

Comment: @Stultuske can you expand on that? What do you mean by "just change it"? If the OP just changes it, existing code that uses this class will no longer compile. Or even worse (if existing code doesn't use `@Override`) it will compile but not do what it did before.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException existing code will only break if they change their dependency to the new version. yes, indeed, that is a risk, but not one they won't be aware of (or at least, can't foresee) before starting the migration. if the existing code doesn't mark it as overridden, that's indeed a risk, but it should hint them into learning about clean coding.
Either way: "getting the new features without changing code", this is ridiculous. they would (at the very least) create a new class to provide implementations of the abstract class any way.

Comment: @Stultuske this may be a cultural thing, but in the Java world, backward compatibility is highly valued. For example, almost all Java programs that were written for jdk 1.0 more than 20 years ago will still compile and run without any changes when compiled with jdk 9. In the case of this question, if a user of MyAbstractClass wants to upgrade the framework so as to use new feature X, they don't want to have to change their code in order to avoid breaking existing feature Y. As I said, new APIs should be backward compatible.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException not even the JRE is (completely) backwards compatible. The problem here is you have to choose between not letting the users use the previous version (meaning adding new functionalities is nonsense), allowing the users to use both versions (at which point there might be a future change in functionality, which I assume is not the goal) or make those who choose to take the last version to strictly use the new version. There is no "good" situation here, they all have their risks

Comment: I've added some additional information to the question - basically it is possible for the application to be updated without the developer of the subclass updating their code.

Comment: at which point you will be changing the functionality of the application without the users knowing. that's a dangerous path, depending on the type of application you're working on

Comment: Changing the signature is not backwards compatible.  You need to *start* with a something like `MyAbstractClass<T extends MyObject>`, so then  `public final void process(T objct)` provides a minimal `objct` for the standard flow.  Of course, `objct` can then be extended, and passed around in the different steps.

Comment: your approach won't work and i think you cannot do this without reflection. what if someone calls `super.step1(...)` from a overwriting method?

Comment: Rather than using reflection, I think it would be cleaner to deprecate this class and create a new one.

Comment: For my actual problem, the solution used ended up being - create a new abstract class and deprecate the old one. This also allowed for re-structuring it in a way as to handle any such cases in a better way.